# GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-places

I have a problem with googlePlace, I don't know how to solve this, thanks for those who will answer

use of unresolved '**GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption**'

**let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.locationRestriction = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(neBoundsCorner, swBoundsCorner)**

- googlemaps: 2.2.0
- googleplace: 2.2.0
- googleplacepicker: 2.2.0
- cocoapods: 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

This is not available in latest SDK.  But available via GMSAutocompleteFetcher. Set Bounds you want to restrict then set auto autocompleteBoundsMode

```
    fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: mapBounds, filter: filter)
    fetcher?.autocompleteBoundsMode = .restrict   // or .bias
```

**Update (on 23rd Nov 2020)**
It seems this has further changed with new SDK. Now "locationBias" is property of GMSAutocompleteFilter. Bounds also moved to GMSAutocompleteFilter from GMSAutocompleteFetcher.

```
var filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter() 
let b = GMSCoordinateBounds(location: location.coordinate, radiusMeters: 100)
filter.origin = location
filter.locationBias = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(b.northEast, b.southWest);
fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(filter: filter)
```